# Java Code to invoke PATCH method from JUnit

Tags: spring-rest

I have a simple MyLibraryApplication which is having code to invoke POST(TransactionControllerImpl.issueBookToMember) and PATCH(TransactionControllerImpl.returnBookTransaction) methods. I have referred some links on net and tried my best to write code to invoke PATCH method. The code can be found in TransactionControllerTest(testBookReturnUsingRestTemplate and testBookReturnUsingMockMvc methods). The code for invoking POST is working fine but the code for invoking PATCH is not working. Control never reaches returnBookTransaction inside TransactionControllerImpl.

**Error: Invalid PATCH method.**

I am looking for code snippet for TransactionControllerTest.testBookReturnUsingRestTemplate and testBookReturnUsingMockMvc methods. Can someone help me in getting this code into proper shape?

```
package com.mycompany.techtrial;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import com.mycompany.techtrial.Transaction;

public interface TransactionController {
    public ResponseEntity<Transaction> issueBookToMember(@RequestBody Map<String, String> params);
    public ResponseEntity<Transaction> returnBookTransaction(@PathVariable(name="transaction-id") Long transactionId);
}



/**
 * 
 */
package com.mycompany.techtrial;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class TransactionControllerImpl implements TransactionController{


  /*
   * PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE SIGNATURE OR METHOD TYPE OF END POINTS
   * Example Post Request :  { "book":"Java8 Primer","member":"Test 1" }
   */
  @PostMapping(path = "/api/transaction")
  public ResponseEntity<Transaction> issueBookToMember(@RequestBody Map<String, String> params){

    String book = params.get("book");
    String member = params.get("member");
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setId(1L);
    transaction.setBook(book);
    transaction.setMember(member);
    transaction.setDateOfIssue(LocalDateTime.now());
    transaction.setDateOfReturn(Transaction.getDefaultReturnDate());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(transaction);
  }
  /*
   * PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE SIGNATURE OR METHOD TYPE OF END POINTS
   */
  @PatchMapping(path= "/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return")
  public ResponseEntity<Transaction> returnBookTransaction(@PathVariable(name="transaction-id") Long transactionId){

        String book = "Java8 Primer";
        String member = "Test 1";
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setId(1L);
        transaction.setBook(book);
        transaction.setMember(member);
        transaction.setDateOfIssue(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(10));
        transaction.setDateOfReturn(LocalDateTime.now());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(transaction);   

  }

}



package com.mycompany.techtrial;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TransactionControllerTest {

  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private TransactionController transactionController;

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate template;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(transactionController).build();
  }


  @Test
  public void testBookIssue() throws Exception {
    HttpEntity<Object> transaction = getHttpEntity(
        "{\"book\": \"Java8 Primer\", \"member\": \"Test 1\" }");

    ResponseEntity<Transaction> response = template.postForEntity(
        "/api/transaction", transaction, Transaction.class);

    Assert.assertEquals("Java8 Primer", response.getBody().getBook());
    Assert.assertEquals("Test 1", response.getBody().getMember());
    Assert.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode().value());

  }

  @Test
  public void testBookReturnUsingRestTemplate() throws Exception {
    Long transactionId = new Long(1);
    HashMap<String,Long> uriVariables = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    uriVariables.put("transaction-id", transactionId);

    Transaction transaction = template.patchForObject(
            "/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return",null, Transaction.class, uriVariables);

    Assert.assertEquals(new Long(1), transaction.getId());
    //Assert.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode().value());

  }


  @Test
  public void testBookReturnUsingMockMvc() throws Exception {
    Long transactionId = new Long(1);

    HashMap<String,Long> uriVariables = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    uriVariables.put("transaction-id", transactionId);
    ResultActions obj = mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
              .patch("/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return",transactionId)
              .content("")
              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    System.out.println(obj.getClass());
    HttpStatus status = obj.andReturn().getModelAndView().getStatus();
    boolean success = status.is2xxSuccessful(); 
    System.out.println("success="+success);

    Assert.assertEquals(new Long(1), transactionId);
    //Assert.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode().value());

  }

  private HttpEntity<Object> getHttpEntity(Object body) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
  }

}




package com.mycompany.techtrial;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Transaction implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8951221480021840448L;

  private static final LocalDateTime defaultReturnDate = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2299, 12, 31), LocalTime.of(12, 0, 0));

  Long id;


  private String book;
  private String member;

    public String getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(String book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public String getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public void setMember(String member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

//Date and time of issuance of this book
  LocalDateTime dateOfIssue;

  //Date and time of return of this book
  LocalDateTime dateOfReturn;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  } 

  public LocalDateTime getDateOfIssue() {
    return dateOfIssue;
  }

  public void setDateOfIssue(LocalDateTime dateOfIssue) {
    this.dateOfIssue = dateOfIssue;
  }

  public LocalDateTime getDateOfReturn() {
    return dateOfReturn;
  }

  public void setDateOfReturn(LocalDateTime dateOfReturn) {
    this.dateOfReturn = dateOfReturn;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Transaction [id=" + id + ", book=" + book + ", member=" + member + ", dateOfIssue=" + dateOfIssue + ", dateOfReturn=" + dateOfReturn + "]";
  }

  //@PrePersist
  void preInsert() {
     if (this.dateOfReturn == null)
         this.dateOfReturn = defaultReturnDate;
  }

  public static LocalDateTime getDefaultReturnDate() {
      return defaultReturnDate;
  }
}



package com.mycompany.techtrial;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyLibraryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyLibraryApplication.class, args);
      }
}
```

[image: Error shown in testBookReturnUsingRestTemplate]

[image: Error shown in testBookReturnUsingMock]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue with the RestTemplate default Http client.

[RestTemplate bug](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spr-issue-migration-test-2/issues/15126)

A workaround for this would be to use the apache httpcomponents httpclient library in the `RestTemplateBuilder.setRequestFactory` and pass that in the constructor to `TestRestTemplate`

After that you can use the `exchange` method on the TestRestTemplate class and do a PATCH request.

Sample code to create TestRestTemplate:

```
Supplier<ClientHttpRequestFactory> supplier = () -> {
   return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
};
restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(supplier);
TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(restTemplateBuilder);
testRestTemplate.exchange("/api/transaction/{transaction-id}/return",HttpMethod.PATCH,null,Transaction.class,uriVariables);
```

Comment: What about MockMvc? For this also a known issue? I'm newbie in this.

Comment: @Prakash I have added sample code for creating a TestRestTemplate.

Comment: Where is the code for exchange method? that's most important.

Comment: Please share the code for exchange method. Without this the answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Prakash I have added it.

Comment: And how did you create an instance of RestTemplateBuilder?

Comment: Have you tested your code on a sample? I have made necessary changes to my code but its not working. Before making changes POST request was working fine, but now that too is failing and PATCH request also failing as earlier. Both are giving I/O error on POST and PATCH request with ResourceAccessException. If you have a tested code sample please share that or else I will have to mark this answer as not useful. Problem is not solved.